# How do I tell how many items I have in my inventory?

Tags: ingress

With the 1.12.5 update to ingress the inventory is now [capped at 2000 items](https://decodeingress.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/ingress-app-update-1-12-5-and-2k-item-limit/ingress-2000-item-limit/).  How can I tell how many items are in my inventory?  Under ops I can pretty easily add up the resonators and xmps, but keys are a little more tedious.  I'm hoping there's somewhere to easily find the count of all these items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way of knowing until you reach the limit for now (v1.12.5)
If you need extra space I suggest dropping Media Items since they are most likely all decoded and redeemed! (or just keep the links bookmarked outside of Ingress)